# To have + past tense vs Gerund

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

> I still remember to have met you in shimla last year

Vs

> I still remember meeting you in shimla last year

what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember in this sort of question is that *there is no general rule*: it depends almost entirely on the requirements of whatever word governs - in this case *remember*.

*Remember* can take an *-ing* clause, so "I remember meeting you".
*Remember* cannot take a to-infinitive clause except in the sense of "remember to do something", where a past infinitive wouldn't make any sense.

Contrast this with *appear* (for example), which takes a *to-* infinitive clause ("They appear to be leaving", or "They appear to have gone" with a past infinitive), but cannot take an *-ing* clause

The meaning doesn't necessarily tell you what kind of clause a particular word can take: it's something that just has to be learnt.

Answer (score 0):

> I still remember **meeting** you in Shimla last year.

This is the correct one, because you are talking about remembering an event that happened in the past.